# Define menu_order on Creation of New Custom Post?

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type called `video` and I'm using a plugin called `Playlist_Order` (which changes the `menu_order` field) to allow the user to use a drag and drop interface to order their videos in a playlist.

However, when adding a new post the video appears at the top of the playlist because it's given a default `menu_order` value of `0`.

On creation of a new video post I would like it to appear last in the playlist - i.e. query all `video` post types, find the largest `menu_order` value and then set this `+1` for the new post.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi **@fxfuture**:

I think what you are looking for is the `wp_insert_post_data` hook. You can add this code to the bottom of your theme's `functions.php` file and/or you can add it to a plugin:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','my_wp_insert_post_data',10,2);
function my_wp_insert_post_data($data, $postarr) {
  $post_type = 'video';
  if ($data['post_type']==$post_type && get_post($postarr['ID'])->post_status=='draft') {
    global $wpdb;
    $data['menu_order'] = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT MAX(menu_order)+1 AS menu_order FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='{$post_type}'");
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike - thanks very much! This works great! Not that it really matters too much but for some reason if I only fill out the title and leave the custom meta fields blank the function doesn't work?

Comment: It may be that `post_status` isn't always `'draft'`; not sure. Is it safe to assume your numbering can start with `1` or do you need to start numbering with `0`? If the former we can change it to avoid any potential mishap with `post_status`.

Answer (score 1):

the 10 & 2 arguments in the end of the add_filter method are:
the priority of the execution (optional default=10)
and number of arguments the new function receives (optional default=1)

the only reason it appears in the code above it's to change the default number of argument.

read more here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer as the post_status draft gave a notice
this will give ALL CPT = page with a zero menu order a unique menu order (highest in database + 5). Adjust to your needs.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'mp_wp_insert_post_data', 999, 2);
function mp_wp_insert_post_data( $data, $postarr ) {
  $post_type = 'page';
  if( $data['post_type'] == 'page' && $data['menu_order'] == 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $data['menu_order'] = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT MAX(menu_order)+5 AS menu_order FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type='{$post_type}'");
  }
  return $data;
}
```