# How do i use postMash to order posts in a custom loop?

Tags: plugins, loop

I'm using the postMash plugin to allow a client to be able to easily reorder posts without having to change the timestamp on each one, and it works fine. However, I'm using a custom loop to call the latest posts in a category onto the home page like so:

```
$i=0;
$events = get_posts( array ( 'category' => 6, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
if ( $events ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $events as $event )  {
        $eventDate = get_post_meta($event->ID, 'event-date', true );
        $eventTime = get_post_meta($event->ID, 'event-time', true);
        echo "<li>".$eventDate;
        if ($eventDate && $eventTime) {
            echo " - ";
        }
        echo $eventTime."<br>";
        echo "<a href='".get_permalink($event->ID)."'>".get_the_title($event->ID)."</a></li><br>";
    if (++$i == 3) break;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

}

The plugin successfully reorders the posts on the category page, but not within this custom loop..

Here's the plugin url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postmash/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin is 3 years old.  I'm not sure if it uses the menu_order column to set the order but if it does you can filter pre_get_posts or your custom query with:

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order'   => 'ASC'
```

This would all have to be done before the $post object is added to the $events array so it would help answer if you added the code that comes before: if ( $events )

Also if you do a var_dump( $event ) somewhere in your foreach loop we can figure out how the posts are being ordered.

### Edit

After your comments and looking at the var_dump here is whats going on:

Your getting 5 posts in proper menu order then your break statement causes the foreach loop to start back at 0 then it posts the same 5 posts again.  It does this 3 times giving you

1-2-3-4-5 break 1-2-3-4-5 break 1-2-3-4-5 break

See the formated $post array dump:  http://pastebin.com/hHPxbzda

If you only want to show the first 3 just add this to your get_posts array:
`'posts_per_page' => 3`

Comment: I added the code before - already called orderby and order..  what values from var_dump would you like me to paste here?

Comment: and do you know if there are any newer plugins that might achieve the same effect?

Comment: var_dump will give you the menu_order assigned to each each post.  All new posts have a default menu_order of 0 which would make them come first unless you create a [save_post hook](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2338/251) that changes it to something else.

Comment: I don't think there is a plugin that does this well but in [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16342/251) all the code is laid out to make it work.

Comment: it's dumping 3 menu_order values per post.. take a look at http://www.antonleroux.co.za/